# SQL replace statement using variables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, data-cleaning

I would like some advice on how to use the SQL replace statement to clean up data with new words that are held in a two columns in separate table.

I am trying to use dynamic SQL and variables to generate the replace statement as below:

```
DECLARE @ReplacementText VARCHAR(max) = 'SELECT UnwantedData FROM Table'

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000) = 'SELECT '

SELECT 
  @sql = @sql + 
  ' @ReplacementText = replace(@ReplacementText, ''' + OldWord + ''', ' + NewWord + ')'
    + ' ,'
FROM ReplacementWords

PRINT @sql

EXEC(@sql)
```

This is a sample of what I get:

> @ReplacementText = replace(@ReplacementText, ' “Saiko Maru”',  SAIKO MARU).

plus the error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@ReplacementText"

Grateful for any tips on how to correct what I am doing or a better way of going about this.

Comment: So, you have  `DECLARE @ReplacementText VARCHAR(max) = 'SELECT UnwantedData FROM Table'` and then you want to replace something in this variable? What is the purpose of your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give below an example of how to do this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE demoReplace(

@tableName varchar(20), 
@fieldName varchar(20)
)
AS 

DECLARE @replacementWords table (
oldWord varchar(50),
newWord varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @replacementWords VALUES ('pudding', 'custard')
INSERT INTO @replacementWords VALUES ('madras', 'vindaloo')

CREATE TABLE #favouriteFoodQuotes (
myFavourite varchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO #favouriteFoodQuotes VALUES ('I adore pudding')
INSERT INTO #favouriteFoodQuotes VALUES ('My dad eats chicken madras every day')

DECLARE @oldWord varchar(50)
DECLARE @newWord varchar(50)

DECLARE @sql varchar(max)

DECLARE repCursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT oldWord, newWord FROM @replacementWords


OPEN repCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM repCursor INTO @oldWord, @newWord

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    SET @sql = 'UPDATE ' + @tableName + ' SET ' + @fieldName 
    + ' = REPLACE(' + @fieldName + ', ''' + @oldWord + ''', ''' + @newWord + ''')'
    EXEC(@sql)
    FETCH NEXT FROM repCursor INTO @oldWord, @newWord
END
CLOSE repCursor
DEALLOCATE repCursor

SELECT * FROM #favouriteFoodQuotes

DROP TABLE #favouriteFoodQuotes

--exec demoReplace '#favouriteFoodQuotes', 'myFavourite'
```

Note that for the sake of illustration I had to create #favouriteFoodQuotes as a temporary table, otherwise the dynamic sql will not run.  But in your case this is no problem as you will pass in the value of a permanent table.  Also I created a table variable to hold old and new words, but again I presume this will be permanent.

Comment: Hi @Johathan - this is perfect and does exactly what I was needing. Thanks very much for taking the trouble to write this in response to my query. Brilliant. I had in mind the need for variables, temporary tables and cursors but definitely couldn't have worked this out myself. Thanks again!

Comment: @SallyF My pleasure.  Glad to have helped

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `@` in the block `@sql + @ReplacementText = replace(` and instead of the `@ReplacementText` inside the dynamic query, you need to make it as variable value as `replace(''' + @ReplacementText + ''',`

The working query will be:

```
DECLARE @ReplacementText VARCHAR(max) = 'SELECT UnwantedData FROM Table';
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000) = 'SELECT '

SELECT @sql = @sql + 'ReplacementText = replace(''' + @ReplacementText + ''', ''' + OldWord + ''', ''' + NewWord + ''')' + ' ,'
FROM ReplacementWords

PRINT @sql

EXEC (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need to clean some words from `SELECT UnwantedData FROM Table` this part.

```
DECLARE @DataToClean NVARCHAR(max)  = 'SELECT UnwantedData FROM Table',
        @ReplacementText NVARCHAR(max),
        @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500),
        @sql NVARCHAR(max) = ' @DataToClean, '

;WITH ReplacementWords AS ( --it is a sample of your table with words
SELECT ' “Saiko Maru”' as OldWord,'SAIKO MARU' as NewWord
UNION ALL
SELECT 'UnwantedData', 'Data I want' --this will work for query above
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Some More', 'Yeah'
)

SELECT  @sql = 'replace(' + @sql + '''' + OldWord + ''', ''' + NewWord + '''),'
FROM ReplacementWords

SET @ParmDefinition = N'@DataToClean NVARCHAR(max),@ReplacementText nvarchar(max) OUTPUT'

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT @ReplacementText = ' + STUFF(@sql,LEN(@sql),1,'')
```

On this part you will get query:

```
SELECT @ReplacementText =  replace(replace(replace( @DataToClean, ' “Saiko Maru”', 'SAIKO MARU'),'UnwantedData', 'Data I want'),'Some More', 'Yeah')
```

IN `@sql` variable, then execute it with parameters:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @ParmDefinition, @DataToClean = @DataToClean, @ReplacementText = @ReplacementText OUTPUT

SELECT @ReplacementText
```

Output:

```
SELECT Data I want FROM Table
```

Comment: Hi @gofr1, Thanks you so much for your help. I think the solution below best meets my needs. I apologize if my original request wasn't very clear and I really appreciate the trouble you have gone to.

Comment: It was my pleasure to help you! :) if any of posts helps you feel free to accept/upvote them, it is a great way to say "thanks"! :)